# Why can't these two mappings be bijective?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, multivalued-functions

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function and define the mapping $\mathbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ by

$$\mathbf{F}(x, y) = (\phi(x, y), -\phi(x, y)).$$

Why can't $\mathbf{F}$ be bijective? Now suppose $\psi : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a different function for which there was a point $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $\psi(x, y) \geq \psi(x_0, y_0)$ for all $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Why can't the mapping defined by

$$\mathbf{G}(x, y) = (\phi(x, y), \psi(x,y)) $$

be bijective?

---

I'm not sure if this is true or not (I would appreciate it if someoen can confirm), but I think that a mapping is bijective on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if and only if each of its components are bijective on $\mathbb{R}$.

If my above claim is true, then $\mathbf{G}$ wouldn't be bijective because the second component function won't hit everything in $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, it wouldn't hit anything less than $\psi(x_0, y_0)$.

Now what about $\mathbf{F}$? I don't have a good reason for this one. Can someone please help me?

Comment: The first function $F$ certainly cannot be surjective, as if $F(x, y)=(a, b)$ then unless $a=b=0$, they are never the same sign. Moreover, as to your first claim that a mapping on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bijective iff each component are bijective, this is not true! Consider $g(x)=x$ the identity map, and let $\chi(x)=(g(x), g(x))$. This is just a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, your second line of reason is correct - if each component is not bijective, then the whole function cannot be bijective.

Comment: How would I reason about $G$ not being bijective then? That just follows from the fact that anything below $\psi(x_0, y_0)$ never gets hit by the second component?

Comment: Let me correct my earlier statement, if each component of the function is not surjective, then certainly the entire function can not be surjective. So your reasoning is almost correct, but I was pointing out that the converse does not hold, if both components are surjective, then not necessarily the entire function is surjective.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thanks so much